# How to delete everything after the last number in a String in Java?

Tags: java

If I have a String that consists of letters and numbers, how can I get rid of everything after the last number in the String?

Example:

- `banana_orange_62_34_wednesday` would become `banana_orange_62_34`
- `1234_4564_www_6_j_1_rrrr` would become `1234_4564_www_6_j_1`

I tried this so far:

```java
int endIndex = inputXMLFilename.lastIndexOf("\\d+");
inputXMLFilename = inputXMLFilename.substring(0, endIndex);
```

Comment: Show us what have you already tried. SO is not "do it for me" site.

Comment: Now that someone cleaned up your post, i can see that. I can also see that you want to return everything before the last underscore, not the last number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex replace:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+$", "");
```

What the regex means:

- `\D` means “non-digit”
- `+` means “one or more of the previous term, greedy (as much of the input as possible)”
- `$` means “end of input”

The `$` *anchors* the match to the end, without which this would match (and delete) *all* non-digits.

---

`lastIndexOf()` only works with plain text, not regex.

Comment: This worked for me. I didnt know the dollar sign was important for this though

Comment: See added explanation of dollar

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void cutAfterLastDigit() {
    String s = "banana_orange_62_34_wednesday";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```